# How to Capture IP packets in java without using JPCAP

Tags: java

Are there any inbuilt Java libraries to capture IP packets that are being sent/recieved on a machine. I do not wnat to use JPCAP for capturing the packets as it depends on libpcap for capturing packets

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no built-in Java libraries for packet capture.